# Check that a method is called before object is collected

Tags: java, destructor, finalizer

I have an object that user typically creates using my factory. I want to make sure my user calls object.undo() before they throw it into the garbage collector.

This class setups the necessary resources so the user isn't writing to production services and instead use test specific services. The user needs to call undo to revert their override.

Here is what I want the user to do

```
// in setup()
FooObject object = FooFactory.overrideProductionServicesToTestServices();

// do your testing in test*()

// in tearDown()
object.undo()
```

Here is what the user end up doing

```
// in setup()
FooFactory.overrideProductionServicesToTestServices()

// do their testing. Everything works.

// Another test, everything breaks
```

How do I notify the user either via throwing an exception or via class design that the user should call undo()?

Comment: An object will not be collected if there is still a reference to it, so keep the reference until `object.undo()` is called.

Comment: I have found that the user do: factory.makeObject() without putting it into a variable. This causes the object to be collected and the behavior of the services erratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a finalizer, which carries a performance impact alongside being rather easy to get wrong, why not store a `PhantomReference` to the created object inside the factory?

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html):

> Phantom references are most often used for scheduling pre-mortem cleanup actions in a more flexible way than is possible with the Java finalization mechanism.

You could have the factory track the associated `ReferenceQueue` for that reference, and once the object is enqueued, perform the cleanup actions ordinarily done by `undo`.

Comment: Since the undo() method belongs to the referent which cannot be accessed via get(), how do I know that my referent has called undo() prior to the PhantomReference be enqueued?

Comment: True -- you can't call undo() directly. However, you could still free whatever resources are being cleaned up by undo when you see the reference get enqueued.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wasn't aware of java references mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make sure my user calls `object.undo()` before they throw it into the garbage collector.

You can implement the `finalize()` method and call the `object.undo()` inside it to make sure it runs first before it's garbage collected.

Like this:

```
protected void finalize()
             throws Throwable {
    this.undo();
}
```

To read more about `finalize()` method, [go to this article on Oracle.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize%28%29)

Comment: Or check that `object.undo()` has been called, rather than calling it. That way, you can test that everything calls `undo` correctly, and then you could remove it from the finalizer later (for performance reasons) without breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

> finalizer can't throw exceptions

[Yes it can](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()), but you must be careful about it. The correct way to call a method in `finalize()` is as follows:

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable
{
    try
    {
       myMethod();
    }
    finally
    {
      super.finalize();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Any exception thrown by the finalize method causes the finalization of this object to be halted, but is otherwise ignored." I meant to refer to the fact that throwing an exception in a finalize method does not inform the user that their code usage is wrong.

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question, don't you? At present it states a falsehood, and doesn't state your requirement correctly.